# Thirty days late is extremely late in internet time

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, late-answers

Please change the requirement that allows an answer to make it into the Late Answers Review Queue (LARQ) here on Stack Overflow. According to [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/177553/244519), the answer must be posted 30 days after the question was asked or later for it to be a late answer. **Please change that to 14 or 10 or 7 days instead.**

There's a lack of reviews that users can do in that queue, so please lower this to help people be able to review more late answers. It will also help find unwanted spammish posts, low-quality posts, answers that aren't answers, users posting comments or questions as an answer, etc. faster than we can find these now. Lastly, it will give *more attention* to answers that happen in this time period, so people can upvote or downvote as they see fit.

Posting an answer 14 days after the question was asked is considered late for most questions on Stack Overflow. Most questions get answered within the first two days. The LARQ can handle a big increase in the number of posts that end up there, so that won't be a problem.

*<sub>**Please Note:** This feature request is definitely not about the fact that I really would like to add a Gold Badge for that queue sometime this century.</sub>*

---

I ran some queries to get a general idea of how many extra reviews this would mean for the late answers queue. Since I'm using [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/help), this only counts **non**-deleted answers, since deleted answers don't show up there.

There have been about **26,751,487** answers posted so far. Deleted or un-deleted. *<sub>Found this by looking at the id of one of the newest answers on the site.</sub>*

According to [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/242615/test) there are currently about **14,070,167** answers that have **not** been deleted. Meaning about **12.6 million** answers have been deleted.

- **12,121,030** <sup>*[query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/242903/test)*</sup> non-deleted answers have been posted < 7 days after the question was asked
- **1,525,719** <sup>*[query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/242902/test)*</sup> non-deleted answers have been posted >= 30 days after the question was asked
- **423,418** <sup>*[query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/242900/test)*</sup> non-deleted answers have been posted >= 7 days but < 30 days after the question was asked
- **192,132** <sup>*[query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/242895/test)*</sup> non-deleted answers have been posted >= 14 days but < 30 days after the question was asked

---

More than 86% of non-deleted answers have been answered within one week of the question being asked. There are very few non-deleted answers that were asked between 14 and 30 days.. so few that I may as well change my request of a late answer being 14 days old, to that of seven days. Or we could meet towards the middle at 10 days old as a compromise.

This data, *although not exact since I can't query the deleted answers themselves*, shows that it would be no problem for the community to handle late answers of two weeks after the question was asked and possibly even a week after. I'd be fine starting out at 14 days and seeing how it goes.

Comment: I'd argue for 7 days on an active site like SO. Especially because a lot of questions tend to seek immediate help with coding problems and, in the majority (I think) of cases, realistically the OP probably has either figured out the problem or moved on just a few days later. With 50 questions per page, 7 days is about 1200-1300 pages in on the question list.

Comment: It would be nice to provide examples of bad answers to three week old questions. Without them, this request has no sense.

Comment: @Basilevs It will also give more attention to the answers that happen in this time period, so that people may upvote/downvote them too.

Comment: *"Posting an answer 14 days after the question was asked is considered late for most questions on SO"*. It's considered late **by you**. There's a subtle difference there.

Comment: @ivarni It's considered late by the statistics.

Comment: The statistics here are heavily focused on whether the load would kill us, yet the description of benefits is quite weak. As long as there is no indication that answers that are posted 15-29 days behind the asking date are often of lower quality, I don't see much justification for the requested change.

Comment: Answer ID need not correlate to number of answers. Example in MySQL: Start a Transaction, insert a row with an auto-increment ID, then rollback the transaction. The auto-increment ID is *not* reset, leaving a "hole" in the answers that have supposedly existed.

Comment: No. The technology cyclus is short, but not so short.

Comment: `DATEDIFF` returns integers so I guess it rounds up or down when the number of days is not a multiple of 7. If I run the query for > 2 weeks and < 4 weeks but use `DATEDIFF` with days instead of weeks (and adjust the tests to > 14 days and < 28 days), I get 153252 answers. And it seems to be there should be some `>=` or `<=` among the queries otherwise answers that sit at a boundary won't be covered by any of the queries shown in the question.

Comment: @Louis Thanks! I have edited the queries accordingly.

Comment: @Basilevs Here's [a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/242941/test) that selects the top 5000 lowest scored answers within that 14-30 day time period. Based on my extensive flagging experience, most NAA's tend to have a score of 0 or so. If you'd like to look through this, be my guest. Remember though, it doesn't include deleted answers within this time period...

Comment: I think the site should be more concerned about good answers than quick ones.

Comment: You've identified a good statistical argument for this proposal. These statistics suggest to me that if answers posted after 30 days are likely to be anomalous, then answers posted after 14 days are also likely to be anomalous. (I wouldn't shorten it further -- this is about identifying anomalies, so we'll get too many false positives if we set the threshold too close to the mean.) There are some counterarguments here and below, but they're speculative. We don't actually know what kinds of answers these are, so the counterarguments won't hold water without more evidence. This should be tested.

Comment: It's not a forum, so all the timeliness arguments go out the window. It's about correct answers, and signal to noise ratio. Truth is not a function of time.

Comment: Interesting that 30 days is considered "late". Considering how fast technology changes I would have thought more questions were being re-answered simply because the solution space to any given question has changed. Accepted answers to question as of 2011 might now be considered deprecated in some significant (<=15%) of cases... tho I have no stats to back that claim. I would expect that that in order to stay relevant SO should brace itself for wave of re-answers simply because old questions will have high PR but are more likely to be outdated than fresh questions asking the same thing.

Comment: @EJP Actually given my comment, I'd argue it is.

Answer (score 41):

The reason late answers are considered suspicious is not just because most questions are answered quickly. It's also because *most questions are old*.

Consider a spammer, picking a question at random (or, more likely, based on a google search). The minor pagerank bump for recently updated pages notwithstanding, it is extremely unlikely that he'll end up at a question that's less than a month old, let alone less than a week old. Now consider if he's picking off the "new questions" list. The questions he posts on will be a few minutes or hours old.

Now, consider a non-spammer user. True, most of his answers will be for recently asked questions... and some will be for very old questions, because he got there through google. But some will be based on watched tags, or questions he read a while ago but never went back to, or... etc.

Both of these groups have a question-age falloff, but it's much steeper for spammers. So I highly doubt that dropping the threshold age would result in anything except more false positives, further diluting an already diluted review queue.

Comment: I agree with this, it is to stop spammers, and why would a spammer post on a question 7 days old? It has not got a high ranking on SEO, and it is not on the SO front page... Two people might view it, at most. So the spammer would just be wasting his time.

Comment: @Joehot200 there's a lot more actions to choose from than flag as spam. Flag as offensive, NAA, low quality, other. Upvote or downvote. Edit. On the most active days, I only get like 6 reviews or so in that queue. We can afford to allow some more late answers in to review. it's a win win. The good answers will get upvotes, and any bad answers or spam/NAAs will be taken care of faster.

Comment: @Joehot200 Exactly. I think most older-question spammers are trying to attach to a particular search phrase or tag.

Comment: "Both of these groups have a question-age falloff, but it's much steeper for spammers" - wait, you're saying that spammers are *less* likely to answer old questions? That doesn't seem consistent with the position you're trying to argue.

Comment: @user2357112 Not quite. The steep falloff means that spammers answer questions that are two minute old or two years old. Regular users also answer newer questions more, but they also answer semi-new questions.

Comment: The question is not _just_ about stopping spammers, as @cVplZ has already reminded. It is unfortunate that the discussion is being hijacked this way.

Comment: Someone just answered a question I asked 8 months ago about port forwarding and it *seems* legit but now I'm paranoid it's spam or some attempt to hurt the internets.

Answer (score 25):

I've found a number of 0-vote late answers to be dramatically useful. I've also found cases where heavily up-voted answers were incorrect or deeply misleading, and only by reading a very late (sometimes over a year later) answer with 0-votes could I make any use out of the "accepted" answer (this latter case happens a lot with dev-ops tasks, where a major accepted answer only works on a specific platform, and lots of later answers clarify how to change the accepted answer to work on your platform -- say like configuring an IDE or a GPU library in an unusual variant of Linux).

I think whether a post is "late" and whether a 0-vote post is "noisy" are *extremely* context dependent and I don't see this as enough of a burden on the community to risk filtering it out with a bad / inconsistent filter. I'd rather have many noisy 0-vote late answers, plus that one important late 0-vote answer, than none at all. The site is more useful to the community (particularly the future community) that way.

By way of an example, [here is a question I asked 2 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510252/efficient-way-to-add-a-singleton-dimension-to-a-numpy-vector-so-that-slice-assig), and for which two people added answers *this year.* The question is old, and the answers are extremely late.

They are not heavily upvoted, but both answers are useful, clearly not spam to anyone who uses NumPy. The late answers are not amazing answers or anything, but I would be afraid of someone who wasn't a NumPy expert coming across that 0-vote answer and removing it because "it's late" or "it's late and not up-voted."

Maybe you will reply by saying that in this case the context makes it clear to you that these old answers are not spam. But how? Do you have a very rigorous and quantitative rubric for what defines that context? Can the community vote on it, or see how it might classify some test cases, before it starts being used? Once we are at that point, I suspect it's just better to leave old answers alone, and let eventual downvotes determine what to delete.

Maybe a better way would be to create an "archivist" badge, which is awarded when a post X days later than the question itself is downvoted by that user, and then later is flagged for deletion, or maybe for 10 such instances, or something. I don't think any more fluffy incentive is needed than that.

Another way to do it might be to turn off the -1 for a downvote in some cases, like when voting on an answer X days later than the post (maybe instead of -1, it just means you can't downvote anything else for 1 hour, or 1 day, or something, but otherwise you don't pay a penalty).

My opinion (based on decades of deep experience with the Stack Overflow servers and spam data sets) is that this all seems like more trouble than it's worth.

Don't impose any opinion of "lateness of the internet" on posts. Just find ways to encourage people to downvote bad answers when they are digging through old posts, and let the downvote system do its job.

Comment: Attention goes does not necessarily lead to negative actions: Good posts could also get an upvote due to the exposure in the late answer review queue.

Comment: how many decades have you been using stackoverflow servers? mortals like us only had access after it was founded circa 2008 :)

Comment: @rupps It was a joke.

Comment: @RobW That is a good point -- though I would speculate due to something like negative selection bias that the rate of old things getting upvoted is drastically lower than new-answer-on-old-thing getting downvoted / deleted.

Comment: Your first two paragraphs, yes, 100% yes. There is frequently that one super-late answer that makes all the difference in the world.

Comment: I was thinking just the same thing today, as I googled around looking for how to do things in python/numpy/pandas. I spent some rep downvoting highly ranked bad answers (some of which would not get a single upvote in 2014).

Answer (score -12):

Late answers, I've found, are commonly contributions from frustrated "new users" with insufficient "reputation" credit to their name to make a simple comment only wanting to improve upon an existing answer.

Putting up *further* barriers to participation is a great way to alienate very highly skilled people who don't have the time to ***FRIST!!*** their way to a high reputation.

Comment: Yes, it may be frustrating for new users. But without the rep barriers, SO would turn into the internet's largest archive of Viagra ads.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. Spite, perhaps?

Comment: Good grief, try again, because "comments may only be edited for five minutes", no phone calls allowed...

Not sure why this would be downvoted, except by spite. The fact I had to "answer" to comment is illustrative of the problem, but in addition, what you say is untrue, because those Viagra ads could very easily be posted ... as answers.

Am I posting Viagra ads in the years since my initial account was activated? No.  Then send my "reputation" up. These barriers are just an excuse for a clique of middling people who have time to be more than occasional dabblers.