# Enhance the "New Answers to Old Questions" moderator tool

Tags: feature-request, 10k-tools

**TL;DR:**

> Enhance the "New Answers to Old Questions" moderator tool by giving me controls to vote, flag, edit, and comment on a post all without leaving the queue.

---

Users with at least 10k reputation gain access to [moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools). The one I find myself using a lot is the ["New Answers to Old Questions"](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions) tool. As its name indicates, this tool presents a list of... new answers to old questions; old questions being questions posted more than 30 days ago.

There are review queues that cover roughly equivalent content. Those are the [Late Answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) and [First Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts) review queues, and are accessible by users with [at least 500 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues). The "First Posts" review includes question and answers that are users' first posts, and the "Late Answers" review is only populated by answers posted by users [with less than 50 rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266696). However, those queues [are always nearly empty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252255/1743880), which is surprising considering that, on average, there is 1 new answer to an old question every 30 seconds (coming up with this number is easy: this moderator tool shows 20 answers by page and one page spans on average 10 minutes; the majority of those answers being from ≤ 50 rep users). As answered in the linked question, it only takes one review to complete it. There is a [feature-request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276078/1743880) to increase that number but it is still without official answers.

The resulting big problem is that a lot of bad answers are going through undetected. Case in point: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29536317/1743880), which is actually a question written in French, survived 11 months without deletion. It went through [first post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/7626923) where a comment was added *and* through [late answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/7627111) where nothing was done. Another example: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36378520/1743880) was reviewed as "No Action Needed" both in [first posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/11870825) and [late answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/11870899), although it is clearly a question and should be flagged as "Not An Answer".

The purpose of this post is to tackle this issue in a different manner: make the "New Answer to Old Questions" moderator tool useful for a variety of curation actions, because it is currently not very usable. The end goal is to attract my fellow 10kers into using this tool so that more content gets reviewed and improved.

---

The main goal of the moderator tool is [to curate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312296/1743880) the new content coming in on questions without activity. As a user, this is what I [roughly want to do](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287337/1743880):

- Review an answer *in context* with the question.
- Flag as NAA / VLQ if appropriate — the new activity is often of the form *Thanks!* or *I have the same problem!* so I want to flag it.
- Review the question — some of the question gettings new activity are, for example, resource requests, which are nowadays off-topic for Stack Overflow, and should be closed when attracting new answers.
- Edit the answer or provide feedback — answers by new users may be badly formatted or poorly worded, so this could be an opportunity to improve their contribution, or provide a comment to encourage them to do so.
- Check for duplicate answers or plagiarism — some answers by new users can be a repeat of an existing answer so I want to comment and possibly flag for plagiarism if appropriate.
- See comments left by other reviewers, to be able to reinforce them or provide more helpful guidance to the author.
- [I want it to be real-time](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/312246/1743880) — think of the poor F5 key

As of today, this is what the tool allows me to do:

- Read the answer.
- Link to the answer and author.
- ???.

Basically, nothing of what I want to do. Here's a sketch of the tool for those interested:

[image: Sketch of the tool]

It is basically a dump of the content of the new answers and nothing else. Which means that everytime I want to perform a moderation action, which is what the tool is supposedly for, I need to click on the question's link and open a new tab, leave the tool, scroll, do what I want, close the tab, continue. This is time-consuming: I don't want to lose my time opening / waiting for the page to load / scrolling / closing tabs; I want to curate. Reviewing pages of new answers is not very engaging to begin with but all this clicking makes it even worse.

---

> Note: There was apparently a change in the rate limiting policy on Stack Overflow in the past month or so. The userscript used below may get you rate limited for a while, so until a fix is done in the script, use with caution!

[Tiny Giant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4639281/tiny-giant) has created a userscript that addresses this, called [NATOEnhancements](https://github.com/Tiny-Giant/myuserscripts/blob/master/NATOEnhancements.user.js). This script greatly enhances the moderator tool by loading the questions and the answers directly in the tool, along with the common curation links you'd see if you opened the post outside of the tool. As such, I can do all of my curating activities **without leaving the page**. Here's a screenshot comparing before / after installing the userscript:

[image: Comparison of installating the userscript]

I have free-hand red circled the awesomeness: I can now directly vote / edit / flag / comment without leaving the page. (For now, it does not do real-time updates.)

Here is another example of a question asking for an off-site resource, and thus off-topic. In such a case, I can easily spot that and vote to close the question [instead of flagging the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264397):

[image: I can see the question!]

My feature-request is therefore simple: I would like to have all of that capability built-in, and thus make the tool attractive for the 10kers.

Comment: The main reason I don't burn all my flags on this queue every day is the amount of effort it costs to handle 1 post, let alone 100. No auto refresh makes it tedious to go back and forth through the pages. I know you do it every day regardless of how long it takes, so kudos to you

Comment: :| that's not a TL;DR, that's a title.  In fact, that's *your title*.  TL;DR sections should *encapsulate, within one or two sentences, the content of your post*. It doesn't have to be complete, but it has to give us **some idea** of what you're on about.  Reiterating your title doesn't count.  In protest, I refuse to consider this widely liked and highly upvoted feature request.  And that matters.

Comment: @Will Thanks for the feedback. Is the thickness of the free-hand red circle correct™? I hesitated between two.

Comment: Yes, those are fine.  I'm a bit leery of non-freehand text, but the shakiness of the lines makes up a bit for that.

Comment: That answer isn't "link only." If you remove the link, it still has a spec of information. A spec, which makes it low quality but not link only. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/216712. The example answer is pretty much exactly like the ones classified as an answer in that post. The difference is that it should be downvoted or improved (preferably the latter), but not deleted. Although the question should just closed here; no sense doing much with he answer. I realize this is a bit of a tangent, but there's already a ton of confusion over not-an-answer issues.

Comment: @jpmc26 Yes, hence me talking about not flagging the answer. And closing the question.

Comment: How did I not even know about the moderator tools?! I must have skipped reading that privilege fully on a busy day!

Comment: @Tunaki Even if the question were on topic, you still shouldn't flag/delete the answer as NAA, though, and your image explicitly calls it a "link-only" answer, which is incorrect.

Comment: @jpmc26 Fine, I'll see if I can update the screenshot. That was not the point of the screenshot. Do note that the debate here isn't whether that particular answer is a link-only answer or not.

Comment: Okay. So now that we've settled the Meta parts of the request, we can move on to the real core of the issue.

Comment: This seems like it would be nice to have, not need to have. If the queue is constantly at 0, it doesn't seem like a very high priority. On the bright side, at least you have a user script for it (which is how many of these niche situations are handled).

Comment: @TravisJ Actually, I think it's important because the queues are always sitting at 0. Looking at the stream of new answers coming in, the amount of posts that would require attention but aren't getting it and the lack of people going through the tool, I feel such an addition could draw more users in it. I often find hours old answers that went through the queues but are still badly formatted or obvious NAA...

Comment: @TravisJ maybe the review queue is often at 0 because it's not being seeded (through the NATO) as much as it could be. I think this feature would allow for more and more efficient seeding, which actually would put **more** posts in the queue because they would be spotted/flagged earlier. Which is in turn a good thing, because then more crap would be deleted (hopefully).

Answer (score 10):

The long term solution for the survival of Stack Exchange should not be - give us more tools/review queues for crap which is already posted on the site. Rather, it should be: - stop the crap before it gets posted.

One solution would be to simply block users with lets say <100 rep from replying to questions that have a certain age. Then as their rep increases, let them reply to older and older posts. Until eventually this "age cap" gets removed entirely (around 2k rep or whatever).

And then for everyone, no matter the rep, perhaps add a message: This post is really old. Are you absolutely sure you have anything of value to add that has not already been said in previous answers?

Another thing that can be done is to make the "protect" flag actually useful. Today I believe it only blocks users with 10 rep or less. That's quite pointless, pretty much all it does is to block spammers. This limit could do with an increase to 200 rep or even more. Usually "protect" is used to save particularly valuable posts, such as "canonical duplicates".

It could also be made so that any answer posted to a protected question automatically ends up in the late answer review queue.

The late answer review queue could be given an option "Duplicate answer. This answer does not add anything which has not already been said in present answers".

And so on.

Comment: This sounds like a totally different feature-request though.

Comment: @Tunaki Yes, perhaps this isn't the right place for it. Anyway, I've given up on feature requests long ago. SO devs are tasked to work with "documentation", "careers" and animating unicorns (the last one being the most likely, given tomorrow's date). Improving the quality of the site has been very low priority for many years.

Comment: I do like this but this goes against one of he principles of SO.  SO wants answers so they want anyone to be able to find a question and be able to answer it.  If we set a rep level needed to answer old questions then we could lose people that are capable of answering but can't because they are blocked.  IDK if it would happen but I could imagine someone getting a minimum rep error and then just walking away depriving us of a useful answer.  I guess we have to weigh would we rather have that or would rather moderate more.

Comment: @NathanOliver more natural barrier to entry (which wouldn't need to involve any rep at all) would be to [let users compare draft of their post against prior answers](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/q/2562/168). Want to add 10th... 20th... 100th answer to an old question? No problem, no rep limits - just compare your draft against _every_ prior answer, one-by-one and _after_ that, go ahead and post it

Comment: @NathanOliver Present problem is that the site is currently drowning in a flood of crap. I think we have to sacrifice the occasional great late answer by some low rep user, in favour of getting rid of 1000 crap answers written by monkeys. The only actual problem I see with this is niche tags, where you could have a guru with a very narrow interest and therefore low rep. Perhaps the lock shouldn't be related to rep, but to the tag. That is, if you have bronze badge in any of the question tags, you are allowed to post late answers.